How do I punctuate a long character story in a poem structured with stanzas?
Indenting without quotes won't work because it will be a children's book with stanzas on different pages. It is a character telling a story with very few "he said" included...most of it is the actual story he is telling, and it spans stanzas. Thank you!

In poetry, punctuation at the end of a verse is often omitted:

we live in a small island stone nation
without color under gray clouds and wind
distant the unlimited ocean acute
...

          ~ Donald Hall, Without

Sometimes poetry plays with punctuation:

How, great,
to, be, a, comma,
and, separate,
one, word, fromma,

nother.

          ~ Brian Bilston, In Praise of the Comma

But in many poems punctuation is used the way it would be used in a paragraph of prose:

Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—
     While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
“’Tis some visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door—
          Only this and nothing more.”
...

          ~Edgar Allan Poe, The Raven

In narrative poetry (that is, a story told in verse), such as an epic poem or a children's book narrated in verse, I would use punctuation as in prose.

Hi Ben, thanks so much for this. I was actually inquiring specifically about a long quote from a character. His story is most of the poem with just two places where it says "he said"...the rest is his speaking. There are several stanzas. So do we just add an open quote and no closed quote for each stanza util the very end (or where "he said" appears)? That is the question. Thanks!
